# Behat ends when click on button submit form

Tags: php, symfony, behat

I use Symfony2 and I have a problem with Behat. My Scenario is:

> Scenario: Add form 
>      **When** Access path **"**symfony_route_path**"**
>      **Then** Fill data form x
>      **Then** Push btn **"**id_btn_form_submit**"**

And Contexts:

(class FormContext extends DefaultContext that is a bit like -> https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/master/src/Sylius/Bundle/ResourceBundle/Behat/DefaultContext.php)

```
/**
 * @Then Fill data form x
 */
public function fillData()
{
    $this->fillField('field_x[name]', 'name');
    $this->fillField('field_y[address]', 'Address');
}
```

(class BaseContext extends RawMinkContext)

```
/**
 * @Then Push btn :button
 */
public function pressBtn($button)
{
    $this->getSession()->getPage()->pressButton($button);
}
```

The output console performs to 'Fill data form x' (runs method completely), but
not show 'Push btn'. 
someone has experienced a similar problem and could help me? I thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: I click on "button".

I have had some problems with it and solved it in this way

About the translation, I'm not really sure if there are some best solution, but I would create a PortugueseContext and call the method you want from there, so...

```
public class overrideMinkContextPortuguese extends MinkContext
{
    /*
    * @When Precionar botao :button
    */
    public function precionarBotao($button)
    {
        $this->pressButton($button);
    }
```

But probably there is a best way...

Comment: This should be a comment (once you have [enough reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) to add one) instead of an answer. Please refer to the [Help Section](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) to learn how to earn reputation and therefore be able to comment.

Answer (score 0):

It is done like below, you don't have to implement any additional method in context class.

Read this [cheatsheet](http://blog.lepine.pro/images/2012-03-behat-cheat-sheet-en.pdf) as well.

```
Given I am on "url"
When I fill in "form_element" with "value"
Then I press "button"
```

Comment: Hi @BentCoder thanks for the pdf,  it well be useful. But even with "I press" has not worked. Another problem is that I speak Portuguese, so I need to write the Scenarios in Portuguese. The real context the option is "@Then Precionar botão: button"

Comment: @dhanielo *then* sentences should be for assertions, not actions.